# Send push when new post is published in a certain category

Tags: plugin-development, categories, hooks

I'm trying to develop a plugin which send a push notification to an app users, when a new post is published on a certain category.
I'm trying with the hook `save_post`, but when the hook is fired, the post has no categories. 
I try `in_category(2)` function, but it always return false.
I try `wp_get_post_categories($post_id)` but always resolve to no categories and the same with  `wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'category')`

I dont know if `save_post` hook is the correct, I think it's fired before the categories are asociated to the post.

How I know if the post is published in a certain category?

Comment: Maybe this could help [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/366021/141080](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/366021/141080)